# distinguishment with sub categories

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am dealing with distinguishing two categories A and B these days and I find that when category B contains some sub categories B1, B2, B3...

Sometimes the distinguish result is better for explicit labeling B1, B2, B3 (the sub categories labels), but sometimes the result is better for gathering the sub categories and just labeling them B.

In the other word, sometimes

```
y=[A, A, A, ..., B1, B1, ..., B2, B2, ... B3, B3, ...]
```

is better, but sometimes,

```
y=[A, A, A, ..., B, B, B, ...]
```

is better.

I think naively there are two impact effect the result:

1. case 1 include more information
2. case 2 the algorithm can focus more on the distinguish of A and B

But I am not sure my assumption is right, anyone knows about it? And when dealing with this case, when there are sub categories, what's your way to get a best result?

Answer (score 0):

In this situation you can use a two-level classifier which first predicts the top-level class, and second selects the most likely second-level class falling underneath. Here is some code that I have used,

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class TwoLevelClassifier(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):
    """
    A two-level classifier intended to be used with labels taken from a 2-level taxonomy. 
    The labels are pipe-separated class-subclass pairs as "class|subclass".

    >>> from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression()
    >>> X = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
    >>> y1 = pd.Series(['A','A','B'])
    >>> y2 = pd.Series(['A1','A2','B1'])
    >>> y = y1 + "|" + y2
    >>> clf = TwoLevelClassifier(LogisticRegression(), LogisticRegression())
    >>> clf.fit(X,y)
    """

    def __init__(self, classifier1, classifier2):
        self.classifier1 = classifier1
        self.classifier2 = classifier2

    def fit(self, X, y):
        y1 = y.str.split('|').str[0]
        y2 = y.str.split('|').str[1]
        self.classifier1.fit(X, y1)
        self.classifier2.fit(X, y)
        self.classes_ = self.classifier2.classes_

    def predict_proba(self, X):
        level1_pred = pd.Series(self.classifier1.predict(X))
        probs = pd.DataFrame(self.classifier2.predict_proba(X), columns = self.classifier2.classes_)
        classes_ = self.classifier2.classes_
        mask = np.array(pd.Series(level1_pred).map(lambda x: [y.split('|')[0] == x for y in classes_]).tolist())
        probs_filtered = probs.where(mask, 0)
        return probs_filtered.values

    def predict(self, X):
        probs = self.predict_proba(X)
        return probs.idxmax(axis=1)
```